# Can't find target .NET Framework 4.0

Tags: visual-studio-2010, .net-framework-version

I am trying on the project with mvcMusicStore, and installed framework v4.0 client.

and when I am trying to target framework to v4.0 from the project it cant be found, where was the problem ?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you will need to download the [complete .Net 4.0 Framework](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17851) in order to get the environment needed to be used in Visual Studio. The client profile from what I can find does not have what is necessary for development.

If the above doesn't work I would suggest trying a repair of Visual Studio as suggested by this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6389368/visual-studio-2010-not-recognizing-net-framework-4-0).

The Full Framework:

> The Microsoft .NET Framework 4 web installer package downloads and installs the .NET Framework components required to run on the target machine architecture and OS. An Internet connection is required during the installation. .NET Framework 4 is required to run and develop applications to target the .NET Framework 4.

Tne Client Profile:

> The Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Client Profile redistributable package installs the .NET Framework runtime and associated files that are required to run most client applications.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the point is I did installed that complete version. and it return the above result. cant find higher framework.

Comment: @kitw You said in your question that you installed the Client Framework. I gave you the link for the Full Installation see if that works for you. Also is this Visual Studio 2010 if so the framework should already be pre installed.

Comment: Sorry My mistyping in comment, what I mean is I did downloaded the link above and installed. and the result return the same, I cant found the framework in the pull-down menu..... and I downloaded v4.5 and the same thing happen, that only v3.5 and below can be choose, not others

Comment: @kitw take a look at this [SO Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6389368/visual-studio-2010-not-recognizing-net-framework-4-0) see if repairing visual studio helps like they suggest.

Comment: That still dont work, is there anyway to directly change the location for microsoft studio express 2010 target framework

Comment: @kitw If you try making a new project, do you have the .net 4.0 framework's as an option?

Comment: When new project create, its default 4.0. and the above "pull-down" menu shows exactly the situation, "null" on the first item

Comment: I worked after reinstall everything .. included studio professional -.-

Answer (score 0):

I was having same problem. and I resolved it by checking `.Net Framework 4 Targeting pack` in `Invidual Components`.

Please see screenshot:

[image]