# How to add dot net version 4.0 in target framework of visual studio 2010?

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

[image]

In my visual studio 2010, target framework only include (2.0, 3.0 and 3.5).
Does not include for 4.0.
So, may I know how can I add dot net 4.0 to show in target framework.
I already install dot net version 4 in my pc.
But doesn't show in target framework.
Please advice me.

Comment: You might want to try some solutions available on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12390175/465053) SO thread.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @RBT. I think it is not ok with my case coz I want to try to use dot net 4 in 2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual studio checks this folder for .net assembly references

```
C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\xxx
```

If that folder is missing 4.0 for you, installing a new version of visual studio may create that folder for you. You could also try copying that folder from a different machine.

If that doesn't work, try the answers suggested here:

[dotnet Framework 4 missing from visual studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3078164/dotnet-framework-4-missing-from-visual-studio-2010)

EDIT: Source for the first suggestion - http://www.anujvarma.com/visual-studio-does-not-display-4-0-or-4-5-framework-option-for-target-framework/